# How to control module federation build file count

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I use webpack module federation in project, and exposes 4 component, it looks like:

```
new ModuleFederation({
  name: 'component1',
  filename: 'remote-entry.js',
  exposes: {
    './Test1': './src/test1',
    './Test2': './src/test2',
    './Test3': './src/test3',
  },
})
```

I built this project, then the result like this:
[build result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeYOo.png)

I get 16 file, except output and remote-entry.js, there still 13 rest, and some of them just less than 1KB.

I tried to adjust optimization.splitChunks, like minSize etc, it doesn't work.

How can I config to reduce assets count.

Comment: Finally，I set optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.defaultVendors and optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.default to false, every expose generate one file.

But it's not a good idea, because some common module will be build to every result.